# Vue Router : function push is not working with Store modification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-storefront

I have a problem with my Vue application with the router on the authentication but only on the first page load...

All my routes are under a middleware to check if they are logged, so my router looke like this :

```js
import Vue        from 'vue'
import Router     from 'vue-router'
import store      from './store'

Vue.use(Router);

let router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'root',
            component: resolve => require(['./views/Root.vue'], resolve),
            meta: {
                pageTitle: `Index`,
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/authentication/',
            name: 'authentication',
            component: resolve => require(['./views/Login.vue'], resolve),
            meta: {
                pageTitle: `Connexion`,
                authNotRequired: true,
            }
        },
    ],
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    //Si l'Utilisateur est authentifié :
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn && !to.matched.some(r => r.meta.authNotRequired)) {
        next({ name: 'authentication' });
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

My session store is quite simple :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VuexPersist from 'vuex-persist'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
    key: 'my.personal.key',
    storage: window.localStorage,
})

export default new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin],
    state: {
        session: {
            sessionId: null,
        },
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn: (state) => {
            return (state.session.sessionId !== null);
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        save(state, session) {
            state.session = session;
        },
        destroy(state) {
            state.session = {};
        },
    },
    actions: {
        save(context, payload) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.commit('save', payload);
                resolve();
            });
        },
        destroy(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.commit('destroy');
                resolve();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And so my Login function is quite simple too :

```js
/* THE FORM WAS SUCCESSFULLY SENT TO THE API WHICH ANSWERED {obj.id: 456} */
onLogIn(obj) {
    this.$store.dispatch('save', { sessionId: obj.id }).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'root' });
    });
},
```

So, this code works fine when the application is already launched, if I disconnect and reconnect, the redirection works fine... Litterally everything is working great ...
**BUT** when the user first load the page and logIn, the router is not pushing the new route so the User stay on the authentication page, but the session is changed (if I put a console.log I have the sessionId in the store)

I don't really understan why the redirection not working on the first load, I found that when I do a localStorage.clear() then reload the page and try to connect it's also not working.

Do you have any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Have you added router in main.js while creating vue instance to access it globally?

Comment: yes ! new Vue({
 store,
 router,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: And the import line too? (import router from './router')

Comment: exactly : import router from "./router.js";

Comment: Check available routes first by using console.log(this.$router.options.routes); and debug further.